# Printing Progress Bar's percentage when animated

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar, progress

I am developing a progress bar which html looks like so

```
<div class="progressbar"><div class="text">%0 Completed</div>
            <div class="progressbar_inner"></div>
        </div>
```

and used this jquery codes for it:

```
$(".progressbar_inner").animate({
                width:"20%"
            },100,function(){
                $(".text").html("%20 Completed");
                });
```

My question is: I want to print percentage of the progress bar when animate started and finished. Like so : %1 Completed %2 Completed and etc.
Anyone helps me?

Comment: Instead of using animate, write your own method that loops and increases the width by 1% using `$(elem).css('width', iterator + '%')`.  In each iteration also set the $(".text").html() to your iterator value.

Comment: you mean do I have to write a function includes parameter called "iterator" or something another?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *step* option of the animate-function:

```
$(".progressbar_inner").animate(
    {width:"50%"},
    {duration: 1000,
     step: function(current_number){
       $(".text").html(Math.floor(current_number) + "% Completed");
     }
    }
);
```

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/JRqVw/